# Windows TPM auth and domain password hash

Tags: kerberos, tpm

In normal AD authentication user enter login and password. From user's password operation system derives a key that's shared with KDC.

Workstation sends KRB-AS-REQ to KDC AS and use derived from user password key to encrypt authenticator.

KDC verify authenticator with it's own copy of user's key and responds with KRB-AS-REP.

How this process changes in case of using PIN code or Fingerprint or face recognition? I'm not talking about Windows Hello for Business.

If user enters pin of use his finger, no password is entered. So, no way to derive a shared key from it.

How workstation gets a shared key in such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you're *not* using Azure AD and/or Hello for Business: There's nothing magic and the TPM isn't even involved, as far as I know. Your PIN merely encrypts your actual AD password that's stored on disk. (It's a bit insecure without FDE, which is why PIN auth needs to be allowed via GPO first.)

If you *are* using Azure AD: *[If I understand everything correctly]* The TPM "stores" a device certificate issued by Azure, which is used to acquire a ticket from an Azure-hosted KDC via PKINIT (a Kerberos extension that allows acquiring TGTs using RSA keypairs, the same as is used for smartcard logon).

AFAIK, there are at least 3 different ways to implement Azure-connected Kerberos, and I do not fully grasp any of them yet.

Comment: Thank you for answer!

I believe, Windows doesn't store password in cleartext, only password hash in memory or encrypted on disk.

So, If you don't use WHfB, you don't use TMP at all? PIN or Fingerprint or face recognition only additionally "encrypt" password hash?

Where can I read more about?

Comment: I don't consider the answer to be fully correct. Wether you use Hello for Windows or a regular smartcard. It all boils down to PKINIT, regardless the secret key is in the TPM cache or the smartcard chip. We are talking about RFC 4556.

Comment: @Michael-O: OP did not mention any smartcards, though – they only mentioned "PIN code or Fingerprint or face recognition" (all of them collectively branded as "Windows Hello" features in Windows), implying it's not a smartcard PIN they're talking about but the "Hello" PIN, which does not involve PKINIT at all.